# javascript count present i value with previous loop output value

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    text += + i + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Count</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to add present `i` value into previous loop output value. This maybe a simple question. I have searched in google and stackoverflow. But, didn't get the desired result.

[image]

In above screenshot,

0 is the previous loop value + 1 is present i returns => 1
1 is the previous loop value + 2 is present i returns => 3
3 is the previous loop value + 3 is present i returns => 6
6 is the previous loop value + 4 is present i returns => 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another persistent variable that keeps track of the last total that was concatenated with `text`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var i;
  var lastTotal = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var newTotal = lastTotal + i;
    text += + newTotal + "<br>";
    lastTotal = newTotal;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Count</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

(technically, you don't need the `newTotal` variable, but it makes the code's intent more clear)

You could also do this a bit more elegantly with `reduce`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let text = '';
  Array.from({ length: 11 }, (_, i) => i)
    .reduce((lastTotal, i) => {
      const newTotal = lastTotal + i;
      text += newTotal + '<br>';
      return newTotal;
    }, 0);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Count</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a second variable to hold the last value:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    sum += i;
    text += sum + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Count</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a `count` of the last number:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var i;
  var count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    count += i;
    text += count + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Count</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce` to fill the operations and then use the function `forEach` to build the desired output.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var html = "";
  Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => i + 1).reduce((a, c, i) => {
    a[i] = (a[i - 1] || 0) + c;
    return a;
  }, []).forEach((n, i, arr) => 
    (html += (arr[i - 1] || 0) + " + " + (i + 1) + " = " + n + "<br>"));

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Count</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd just use an array so that you both have the previous sum, and can also use it with `.join()` for setting the HTML.

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0, a = []; i <= 10; i++) {
    a[i] = i + (a[i-1] || 0);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Count</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```